# Lottie-iOS Touch Events

Tags: android, lottie

I had a full-screen Lottie file including several elements in this view. I want to get some kind of callback when users click on these elements.

For example, there is a bird, a snake, a tiger, and a hunter, etc. in this animation view. When users click the bird, it will fly to the sky. And if users click the snake, it will sticking out its tongue.

Is this possible?

Comment: cause I wanna build a game-like app.its first view is a full-screen lottie animation view and I hope its interactive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.